# A random call for a style.css action, which doesn't exist - Why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, coding-style

My error logger has logged an error recently that just boggles me.

Here's a copy'n paste of the error:

> A public action method 'style.css'
>   could not be found on controller
>   'ProductController'.

So I ran a search over the entire solution for references to style.css. There are none, and I have no stylesheet named style.css.

The calls are happening on a legitimate users logged in session even. W.T.H?

Comment: Use FireBug's net tab to inspect all requests performed by given web page.

Comment: Perhaps someone wanted to look at your css file and tried to enter the URL to the css in their web browser? something like: http://host/Product/style.css etc.

Comment: Can you reproduce it at all?  If so, you could run fiddler on the server and look for the URL?  Might help you find the reference.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I'll try all those things. I suppose I could reproduce it by trying to load style.css like Terje mentioned. The weird thing is, the users are local to me and I have a hard time believing they tried to look at the stylesheet. Additionally, my stylesheets are compressed and combined into a asset.axd call, so they'd never even see the text style.css - which isn't even what the stylesheet is called at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used Firebug to find the call... it was coming from a jQuery plugin. Resolved by setting the stylesheet name in the plugin options.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that there's a route mapped in a way that's "catching" '/style.css'.

Comment: Could be... but what the heck is making a call to style.css? I have never even used a stylesheet named style.css. It's happening on a page where the user must be authenticated so it's not an outside call. Also, the stylesheets are compressed and combined into a asset.axd call so even if they viewed the source, there's nothing called style.css. I'm confused...